# Symfony2 Functonal Tests, query parameters are ignored

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

How do I send additional parameters with a request in a functional test in Symfony2. I have

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request("GET", '/timezones/23.html?X=1', array("rest_auth" => "wrong"));
```

Both `X` and `rest_auth` are missing when the request hits my Symfony2 application. I have tried it with `POST` too and even with

```
json_encode(array("rest_auth" => "wrong"))
```

Nothing seems to work in sending additional query parameters to the request.

Comment: Could you provide the code of the controller action you are trying to test?

Comment: How are you accessing the GET parameters in your controller? I just tested your $client->request version (with symfony2.3) and it seemed to send both of the value pairs correctly to my controller ( visible with `var_dump($this->getRequest()->query->all());` )

Comment: I do not see how this is related to PHPUnit.

Comment: @ejuhjav thats it! I was using `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @SebastianBergmann I am running it via phpunit

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this will work for the passed params

```
$req->get("timezone")
```

But this will not

```
$_REQUEST['timezone']
$_GET['timezone']
```